# How to load Google Map API key

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

i have downloaded an open source code from https://github.com/geirke/optimap and his code is working on his live site at http://gebweb.net/optimap/ however i get the following error in the browser console when attempting to run on my own server

Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired

Of course i went and got an API key for my self but no matter what combination of passing the API key i do it does not work. Here are the following attemps

```
function onBodyLoad() {
google.load("maps", "3", {callback: init, other_params:"sensor=false"});
}

function onBodyLoad() {
google.load("maps", "3", {key: "abcdefghijklmnop", callback: init, other_params:"sensor=false"});
}

function onBodyLoad() {
google.load("maps", "3", {key: abcdefghijklmnop, callback: init, other_params:"sensor=false"});
}
```

I have searched online and I see that google does not require an API key, and passing the api key via an argument such as ?api=abcdefghijklmnop&callback ect.

If someone would be kind enough to assist me ive been at this all day. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the key in the "other parameters" field:

```
google.load("maps", "3", {callback: init, other_params:"key=abcdefghijklmnop"});
```

(the sensor parameter is no longer required, but the API key is).

Comment: Thank you, this will help others in the future for sure.

Comment: Note that google.load('maps', ...) is no longer to be supported by Google.
[Google Loader Migration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/google-loader-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are requiring the correct js file prior to any google maps code. It should look something like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

Then replace the XXXX with your api key.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I needed to pass the key in the other parameters and use the newer version of the map. Update your answer and i will give you the green check :) 

 
  function onBodyLoad() {
   google.load("maps", "3.24", {callback: init, other_params:"key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"});
  }